# maven dependencies conflicts

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

I got the following error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/me/mycom/poc/spark-streaming/src/main/scala/com/mycom/poc/App.scala:15: error: object mycom is not a member of package org.apache.spark.io
[ERROR] import io.mycom.myproj.schema.event.Event
```

There is a dependency called `io.mycom.myproj`. it is conflicted with `org.apache.spark.io`. How to fix it? Thanks

My pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.myproj.myproj</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproj-client</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.mycom.myproj</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproj-kafka-security</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.compactVersion}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.compactVersion}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.compactVersion}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>0.10.0.0-SASL</version>
    </dependency>
```

My imports in App.scala:

```
import org.apache.spark._
import io.mycom.myproj.schema.event.Event
```

**UPDATE**

I changed import to:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf // <= fixed the problem
import io.mycom.myproj.schema.event.Event
```

Comment: Could you show the code?

Comment: Could you show the pom.xml?

Comment: @JFMeier Updated. Thanks

Comment: @Alexis Dufrenoy Updated. Thanks

Comment: Those imports are from App.scala, I guess?